# positioning a link on a image using css

Tags: css

I have a link and an image. I would like to use css absolute positioning to position the link on the image but if i use css absolute positioning then the link will not be properly positioned if the user is using a bigger monitor or a smaller monitor. How could I make it so that it would work on all monitors and be positioned correctly.

Comment: show us an example on jsfiddle please with your code and what you expect how it should be.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/81vrt8xo/

Comment: it does not show the exact problem but basically the problem is the link moves when the monitor is bigger

Comment: Always post the code in question *in* your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one is really daft, but just move the link so it wraps around the image?

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
```

The other alternative (if you can't do that), is to make sure they are in the same parent element that is `position: relative;`:

```css
#container {
  position:relative;
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
}
#container a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <a href="http://www.google.co.uk"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the image a background image, reformat as below, if possible. (this is a **better** practice)

*Is there a reason it MUST be a foreground image? Let me know and I might have a suggestion specific to that!*

```
#divwithimage { 
   background: url("../images/sweet.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   position: relative; // as this will act as parent
}

button {
  position: absolute; // absolute to container above
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: could you please post a demo on jsfiddle